# Java FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

This is probably something incredibly dumb on my part, but I've been fighting with it for an hour.

Given these classes, all in the same package:

- ParsingClass.java
- CatalogHandler.java (extends DefaultHandler, adds a ConfigMap field)
- hd.xml

Since the class and the XML are in the same package, I didn't expect to have to fight to find the XML file. Unfortunately, the best laid plans often go awry.

```
private static Map<String, Object> parseCatalogXml(String catalogName) {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    CatalogHandler handler = new CatalogHandler();

    try {
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        File file = new File(catalogName + ".xml");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to find file: " + file.getName());
        }
        parser.parse(file, handler);
    } catch (SAXException ex) {

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }

    return handler.getConfigMap();

}
```

Using new File("").getAbsolutePath() didn't work from either the IDE or using maven on the command line.

Comment: Just check what is returned by `file.getAbsolutePath()`. Seems that your app is launched in root dir, whereas your xml in package subdir, hence you'll need to build file absolute path to get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a classpath/working directory issue @Jason.  Even though your file is "all in the same package", that doesn't mean that Java is running in that directory.

What you most likely need to do is move the XML file to another "source folder" (Eclipse language).  In my projects I have my source in:

```
src/main/java
```

and my XML and other config files in:

```
src/main/resources
```

Then you can find the XML files in the top of the classpath with something like:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(catalogName + ".xml");
```

Comment: That worked. It looks like something someone would say isn't the "right" way to do it, but one of Murphy's laws of combat states "If it's stupid but it works, it isn't stupid".

Comment: No, as far as I know it _is_ the "right" way to do it.  It is especially correct if you package your project in a jar or otherwise deploy it.  In these cases, the config could exist only in a jar and not in an excessable `File` at all.

Answer (score 0):

when you load hd.xml like this, the file needs to be located in the same directory from where you start your programm with.

Which means, calling java in /home/user/ then the hd.xml needs to be located in /home/user/hd.xml.

Comment: Since I need to package the xml file with the application, can you tell me what I need to fix? Since I build with Maven, I tried putting it in a src/main/resources directory with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just doing `new File("file.txt");` will look for a file in your *working directory* (the directory from which you started the program).

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your file with:

```
new File(getClass().getResource("/"+catalogName + ".xml").getPath());
```

Comment: Ok, you can use YourClass.class.getRessource() then.

Answer (score 0):

If hd.xml get packed with your program you should read [Class.getResource()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).